# Как передать классу изначально неизвестное количество параметров?

Tags: php, синтаксис

Изначально класс инициализировался вот так

```
$klas = new klas([
                    ['text' => 'txt1', 'data' => '1'],
                ], [
                    ['text' => 'txt2', 'data' => '2'],
                ], [
                    ['text' => 'txt3', 'data' => '3'],
                ]);
```

Появилась необходимость запустить его с изначально не известным количеством аругментов, все они находятся в массиве `$items`

```
    foreach($b->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $item){

        $items[] = ['text' => $item['id'], 'data' => $item['data']];

    }
```

Как запустить класс из первого примера с массивом из второго?

Comment: Use the [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.func-get-args.php), Luke!

Comment: @Aid ох аид, аид  http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new  ..... В версиях PHP 5.6 и выше список аргументов может содержать многоточие ..., чтобы показать, что функция принимает переменное количество аргументов

Comment: @Aid у js spred с 2015, PHP5.6 вышла  28 Aug 2014. Выводы делайте сами :)

Comment: @Aid это черновик. а в черновике у пыха соответсвенно было еще раньше 2014 :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский то что надо